# What is the Conncetion String format of SQL AnyWhere

Tags: crystal-reports, database-connection, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to connect to SQL AnyWhere by using Crystal Report.
But i dont know the correct format of conncetion string.

Answer (score 0):

> We've only supported connecting to Sybase in recent versions using
>   ODBC only. You may be able to use the DSNless connection option. In
>   the ODBC connection UI you can specify a connection string, this does
>   require the Sybase ODBC client be installed and configured. I have not
>   played with it lately but it may work for you.
>   refer link http://scn.sap.com/thread/1270385

You can connect with ODBC connection as given link here and link as

```
"crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("dbo", "dbo", "ODBC; Driver=Sybase SQL Anywhere 8.0", "DC", true);"
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/842251/How-to-connect-the-sybase-database-in-Crystal-repo

http://sqlanywhere.blogspot.in/2014/12/connecting-to-foxhound-3-with-crystal.html

http://codeverge.com/sybase.sqlanywhere.general/crystal-reports-and-sql-anywhere-1/1007272